# Array subscription execution order

Tags: c, arrays

How this code fragment work for array subscription execution direction.
Please explain.

```
static int a[][2][3]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
int i=-1;
int d;
d=a[i++][++i][++i];
printf("%d",d);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work; your line with multiple `++` invokes undefined behaviour.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior.

Comment: This code works. gcc 4.8.1 results d = 2.

Comment: It's just bad luck that it exhibits the desired behaviour.  Switch to a different compiler, version, platform, etc., and it may exhibit different behaviour.

Comment: @imran_khan Read this http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/

Comment: There is not even any "desired behavior" here, because in addition to the undefined behavior, the order of evaluation of those 3 sub-expressions is unspecified. So if you expect this code to behave in a certain way, you are basing your expectations on something you made up yourself, out of the blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This invokes undefined behaviour. Quoting C99 standard §6.5 ¶2

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value
>   to be stored.

There is no sequence point in the evaluation of the array index in

```
d = a[i++][++i][++i];
```

Therefore, it's not known when the side effects of evaluation of expressions in `[]` will take place. Quoting C99 stanadard again §6.5.2.1 ¶2

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is
>   identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

Therefore, the expression `a[i++][++i][++i]` evaluates to

```
   a[i++][++i][++i]
== *((a[i++][++i]) + (++i))
== *(*((a[i++]) + (++i)) + (++i))
== *(*(*(a + i++) + (++i)) + (++i))
```

Adding parentheses does not create a sequence point. It only defines the order of evaluation of sub-expressions of the complete expressions. It does not guarantee when the side effects of evaluating the sub-expression will take place.

Comment: Is there a direction for executing array subscription?

Comment: @imran_khan please see my updated answer. There is a order in evaluating the array indices.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[i++][++i][++i]
```

This statement results in undefined behaviour.
you can try executing code [here](http://codepad.org/k7v4mptv) and you will get different output than `2` that you got. Its not that you will not get output but the behaviour is undefined so you cant predict the output.